# MailChimp response code 200

Tags: php, httpresponse, mailchimp

I am running the MailChimp `subscribe` API call. The JSON object sent looks like this:

```
{  
   "apikey":"someAPIkey-us10",
   "id":"someID",
   "email":{  
      "email":"example@su.vi"
   },
   "merge_vars":{  
      "products":[  
         {  
            "name":"prod",
            "url":"https:\/\/www.example.co.uk\/properties\/link\/sub\/res",
            "price":"\u00a3378.00",
            "location":"loc",
            "area":"are"
         }
      ]
   },
   "double_optin":false
}
```

and the php code that executes the `curl` object looks like:

```
$curl = curl_init(SEED_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonStr);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($jsonStr)
    )
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo ($curl , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($responseCode !== 201) {
        throw new Exception("post failed with response code " . $responseCode . " " . $jsonStr, 1);
    }
```

the `$response` dump is valid and looks like:

```
"{"email":"example@su.vi","euid":"someEUID","leid":"someLEID"}"
```

However a

> post failed with response code 200.

is thrown, and the subscribers list is not being populated in the mailChimp server.

Comment: Can you see your new subscriber in the list, now?

Comment: @Pierre-JeanBergeron, I do. But the issue was not about waiting. It was because I was passing the `email` first and then the `apikey` to the `subscribe` method. I had another look at the documentation, and followed the arguments order.
Merci beaucoup quand même! :)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP code 200 means that your request was successful. See https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/

You just have to wait a few minutes to see your subscribers list populated.